# Pros/cons of relying on rowid instead of _id primary key (SQLite)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a mapping table that essentially maps primary keys of one table to primary keys of another table (plus a few other columns). There are indexes on both of those columns that reference primary keys.

I'm wondering if I need the _id primary key for the mapping table. In queries, I can simply reference rowid instead of _id.  FWIW, the database is not modified after it is created.

What are the advantages of creating the _id column?

Comment: Disadavantage, althouhg not asked for, is wasted space. Would you ever envisage using it to access a row or rows (likely not)? 1 advantage is if using a cursor adapter, as as cursor adapter requires _id column (easily circumvented), can't think of any other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many parts of the Android framework expect your queries to return a unique integer column called `_id`.

If the contents of the mapping table never show up in such an Android component (e.g., looking up both names and showing the name1/name2 mappings in a list view), then you don't need it.

However, ([almost](http://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html)) all tables have the internal `rowid`, so it would not hurt to declare it explicitly as `_id`, especially if you do not know if you might ever need it.

Referring to it as `rowid` is not always a good idea because without an explicit column, [its value might change](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html).

Comment: excellent point regarding VACUUM potentially changing the rowid. I didn't know that. Presumably it wouldn't change the order of the rows though. I hope not anyway!

Answer (score 2):

If _id is primary key and of integer type, then it becomes an alias of **rowid**.

So there isn't much difference.

Though it could be inconvenient to include rowid in insert: [`INSERT INTO test1(rowid, a, b) VALUES(123, 5, 'hello');` (From sqlite.org)](http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

Comment: regarding insert, aren't the two cases synonymous?  i.e. INSERT INTO test1(rowid, a, b)... vs. INSERT INTO test1(_id, a, b)...

Comment: @techehcet yes, but in the case of `_id`, you can simply use `INSERT INTO test1 VALUES`. No need to specify column names.

Comment: ah okay, I presumed that would work the same, but now I guess not!